# SSD recognized by BIOS but not by Win 7 System Recovery Tools

Tags: windows-7, ssd

**Situation:**
Desktop PC with SSD (Corsair) as main disk with Win 7 on it. Sudden blue screen today and since then I cannot boot anymore. After many unsuccessful hours now, I turn to you.

The SSD is recognized by the BIOS (MSI mainboard). However, if I enter the Win7 setup disk and enter the System Recovery Tools, no installed windows is recognized and no disks are found by *wmic* or *diskpart* on the command line.

Trying to start windows in Safe Mode hangs on ClassPNP.sys.

**EDIT 1:** Update: I now received my SATA->USB adapter and plugged it into my laptop. The SSD gets partially detected meaning, that in the explorer it starts coming up as four different partitions (there are three actual partitions on the SSD), but only the first one (small 100MB, not one of my three real ones, so probably this is a technical/administrative disk area) shows a size info and can be accessed, although it appears to be empty. Once the laptop completely scanned, all four entries disappear and windows asks me if I want to format the drives. Disk Management does not list the drive.

**EDIT 2:** Plugged the SSD again into my desktop and it automatically entered System Recovery Tools without any Win 7 boot DVD put in. That to me sounds like the SSD is at least working partially, since these tools need to be loaded from somewhere. The problem is though, that the System Recovery Tools do not recognize any windows installation.

***Any ideas on what to try next in order to save the data and possibly get the system back running at least once?***

Comment: Tried the drive on another system?

Comment: Not yet able to, since no adapter available (SATA->USB). Currently trying to procure one online to be delivered tomorrow to do that check. Any other ideas in the meantime?

Comment: Not really anything that comes to mind that you're any more likely to be able to try, it sounds like it's just toast to me.

Comment: So the fact that the BIOS still recognizes it, is no particular good sign and would still be the case even if the SSD is indeed completely broken?

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier - Until you verify it works in another system any suggestions will have to wait.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier - The drive being recognized simply means the controller on the drive is reporting its existence properly (and the SATA controller in your system is recognizing it) - that doesn't mean the storage functionality of the drive is working, necessarily.  The fact that diskpart doesn't see it is a bad sign IMO.

Comment: How does the fact, that when I try to enter Safe Mode I can see that it starts loading drivers successfully until CLASSPNP.sys, fit in? Wouldn't that mean that to a certain degree the drive still has to work?

Comment: Added **EDIT 1**

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier Grab a Linux LiveCD...usually that will find partitions/data that Windows doesn't want to show.

Comment: I already booted an Ubunutu, but it did not list anything except the DVD drive with _parted -l_ and _fdisk -l_ did not react at all. Anything else I should try in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know that I eventually was able to find a solution:

With the help of ***[Hiren's Boot DVD 15.2](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)*** and more specifically the bootable *Parted Magic 2012-10-10* version on it, I finally found a way too read the crucial data from my SSD apparently was still working to a degree but not properly, since Windows still ignores it as do other Linux derivatives (as I mentioned I tried Ubuntu earlier without any success).

Even with GParted it took multiple runs, because after some time the SSD automatically gets unmounted and I had to reboot into GParted again to continue my copying efforts.