# NTFS seagate ST31000528AS drive can be accessed from various linux distributions but not from Windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows, ntfs, hard-drive-failure

This a windows 7 NTFS system drive that stopped booting windows.When seen from a windows repair boot DVD it appears as RAW.Seagate diagnostics (Seatools) Fails at 10% of simple diagnostics.BUT various Linux distros can mount the drive, report status OK and 2 bad sectors, and I have copied ~300Gb of data out of the drive (albeit at turtle pace) by using a lubuntu distro.Why windows cannot see the partition?.What does windows do in a different way? And why linux just works?.(this is a question to educate myself since the data extraction succeeded somehow and there is no pressing need for a response)

Comment: the drive is probably starting to get damaged, the Linux might soon stop reading the drive as well. Make a backup as soon as possible before that happens

Comment: As I mentioned in the last phrase the backup is already done and the drive discarded.But the question is about the technical reason the 2 OS's have different behavior.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/586666/why-can-linux-systems-sometime-recover-data-windows-cant-any-concrete-reasons